# Is mentioning the word 'exercise' enough to make nutrition on topic?

Tags: discussion

I was looking at [this question on glucosamine](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/40952/is-glucosamine-use-okay-when-doing-keto?noredirect=1) and initially closed it as being off topic, as I did not notice the word exercise included in parentheses.

I reopened it pending the outcome of this meta discussion, as I don't feel that just saying "I exercise" is enough to bring a nutrition question on topic. The determinant for nutrition since the scope change has always been [nutrition as it relates to exercise](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Is saying "I exercise" followed by a nutrition question enough?

Answer (score 2):

I would say it's not sufficient just to invoke the word "exercise" in hopes that it dodges a close vote.

In order for the exercise aspect to play even a small role in the question or any answer, we need to be able to factor in what kind of exercise and regimen we're talking about.

1. Without "I exercise" I would close it as off-topic.
2. With "I exercise" I would close it as too broad, because there are just too many unknowns now, and there is no one-size-fits-all answer. It would actually be easier to answer if he said he *didn't* exercise, but of course, back to point 1 then.

The question would be redeemable, and even a good addition to the library of questions, if it had the relevant details.